# Looking for raw spectral data in the time domain.... so I can do my own FFT analysis on it

Tags: fourier-transform, spectroscopy, data-analysis

I'm trying to get the spectral data of the periodic table of elements in the **time domain format** or find a site that has the data in the **time domain format**. All the sites I know have the data in the frequency domain which is great but I need to do my own fft analysis starting from the time domain because the frequency domain does not include the **phase angle data**, which I also need to use for my calculations/animations. Does anyone know where I can get this data or can someone send me the spectral analysis data for sodium and potassium in the time domain? If this is the wrong forum to ask this question can someone tell me the correct one.

Comment: What about using a minimum phase reconstruction? That may seem arbitrary, but could possibly work?

Comment: @claudechuber how accurate is minimum phase reconstruction?  I could test it out on a known audio signal to see if it would work. I looked for a quick explanation on youtube but couldn't' find any.   Is there a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: One cannot say it is accurate, as it relies on the arbitrary choice of concentrating the main part of the signal at its beginning - which may or may not be the case for the original signal. If you have Matlab, you can use the [rceps function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rceps.html).